# Determine the super class reference used to call method in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been asked this a couple of times, & am completely stumped on how and why one would go about it.

Here's the scenario:

```
interface IntA {
    void someMethod();
}
interface IntB {
    void someMethod();
}
```

Two simple interfaces; implemented below in a simple class

```
class ClassAB implements IntA,IntB {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(){
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Then we could instantiate & use like so:

```
IntA a = new ClassAB();
a.someMethod();
```

or through the other interface:

```
IntB b = new ClassAB();
b.someMethod();
```

Now the question is in the implementation of `someMethod()`, can I find out if they used an `IntA` reference or an `IntB` reference to invoke `someMethod()`. And accordingly, execute different logic.

I honestly feel this is just the wrong question. I don't understand why & how one would do that. From the interfaces point of view, it has an implementation that meets the criteria of the function signature & that's all that matters. If `IntA` & `IntB` expect different results, then they ought to be implemented in two different classes.

I've come across this scenario twice, hence why I'm asking. Is there really a way to determine? Is there some way to do it in other languages like `C/C++`?

Comment: If the interfaces want different functionality, they should use different method name...

Comment: What scenario did you come across where it matters?

Comment: @daniu It was an interview question. I came across this same question by two random interviewers months apart. The first I guy I simply thought was in the wrong mindset. Then when a 2nd guy asked the same thing, I got a little doubtful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only can't you really do that (except with some complicated wizardry), but as you've said, there's no good reason to even try to do it.

The only scenario where this might even come up, is if you've accidentally given same method signatures to 2 interfaces that are commonly used and may end up being implemented in the same class together, but with distinct functionality. But that's a design error on the interfaces' part.

There's no clean way around it, and even an unclean way would be so complicated that nobody in their right mind would attempt it. The correct course of action would be to refactor either one of the interfaces to use a different method signature. It could also be a sign of bigger design problems if this scenario has come up *twice* already.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. When I mentioned I came against it twice - I meant I came across it in two different interview sessions. I feel they saw something like this in another language & were just assuming Java must also have it.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that `there's no clean way around it` means "if the interviewing company requires it, they design bad software". I would ask them if they really do that and be very open about me questioning its necessity.

Comment: It's really hard to know sometimes what the interviewer is hoping to hear. They're people too, so you might get questions that are formulated poorly, or even completely wrong in case the interviewer is not up to his task. Especially in the current market situation where it's hard to find **good** programmers, the interviewers may not be the experts they make out to be.